# Delete duplications in JSON file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am trying to reedit json file to print only subgroups that has any attributes marked as "change": false.

Json below:

```
{"group":{
    "subgroup1":{
        "attributes":[
        {
            "change":false,
            "name":"Name"},
            {
            "change":false,
            "name":"SecondName"},
            ],
        "id":1,
        "name":"MasterTest"},
    "subgroup2":{
        "attributes":[
            {
            "change":true,
            "name":"Name"
            },
            {
            "change":false,
            "name":"Newname"
            }
            ],
        "id":2,
        "name":"MasterSet"},
}}
```

I was trying to use command:

`cat test.json | jq '.group[] | select (.attributes[].change==false)`

which produce needed output but with duplicates. Can anyone help here? Or shall I use different command to achieve that result?

Comment: That's not valid json and jq might have problems parsing it. Also: What is the expected output?

Comment: Can't address the actual question until you fix the JSON, but as a general note, `cat anything | ...` is better replaced with `<anything ...`; when you give your program a real file handle instead of a FIFO it can do things like parallelizing IO, or detecting the file's length before reading all the way to the end (for progress info), or skipping around (for much more efficient implementation of tools like `tail` or `tac`), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.attributes[]` iterates over the attributes, and each iteration step produces its own result. Use the [`any` filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any%2Cany%28condition%29%2Cany%28generator%3Bcondition%29) which aggregates multiple values into one, in this case a boolean with the meaning of "at least one":

```bash
.group[] | select(any(.attributes[]; .change==false))
```

```json
{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "change": false,
      "name": "Name"
    },
    {
      "change": false,
      "name": "SecondName"
    }
  ],
  "id": 1,
  "name": "MasterTest"
}
{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "change": true,
      "name": "Name"
    },
    {
      "change": false,
      "name": "Newname"
    }
  ],
  "id": 2,
  "name": "MasterSet"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jo9wKc1puKK)

Comment: One more question. Could you also advice how to remap this JSON if I would like to see in subgroup "MasterSet" only the attributes with "name" = "Newname"?

Comment: @strmgr Then find the subgroup matching `.name == "MasterSet"`, and `map` its `.attributes` array to only contain those items matching `.name == "Newname"`: `… | select(.name == "MasterSet").attributes |= map(select(.name == "Newname"))` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/74uwzw5XpvF). Note that this is based literally on your follow-up question. Just showing the previously matched attributes (having `.change==false`) is a completely different approach (`.group[] | .attributes |= map(select(.change==false))` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XSCXvW7fp6B)) but yields the same result for this sample data.

Comment: Big thanks once again! Its helping me a lot!

Comment: One more question - is there any option to sort printing of attributes in that array? Ex. first  `"name":"Name"` and as second `"change":false`? How to do it also in the top hierarchy ex. first `"MasterSet"` and second `"MasterTest"`

Comment: I think that would be last question finally :)

Comment: @strmgr JSON objects do not have a field order, only arrays have an item order. So, if you are destructuring the object anyway, you can first collect its field values into an array, then sort and destructure that. This can be applied to the object held by `.group` (your outer case) which you were destructuring with `.group[]`. So, replace `.group[]` with `[.group[]] | sort_by(.name)[]`, and you're good to go. With the inner case, however, it depends on what you actually mean (maybe I jsut misunderstood). Ordering the items of the `.attributes` array is straightforward: As it's an array … (1/3)

Comment: … just complete your filter with `| .attributes |= sort_by(.name, .change)`, and it will be sorted by the criterion given first, and in case of a tie by the one given second. But if it's its items themselves you want to see ordered, it gets challenging because they're objects which, as stated above, do not have an order, and as such just cannot be sorted properly. Of course, the fields do show up in one but that's at the JSON processor's own descretion. Any (other) processor applied subsequently may very well disregard that order. Where to go from here? You could "take that risk", and … (2/3)

Comment: … lure the jq processor into producing a specific order by constructing new objects while providing it the fields in your preferred order. Use a mapping to reach all items of the `.attributes` array as in `| .attributes |= map({name, change})`. The other way would be to collect the field values into an array, but this time along with their field names, sort the array by the latter, and keep the values. This will reliably give you the ordering but at the cost of losing the (unordered) object structure to an orderd array: `| .attributes |= map(to_entries | sort_by(.key) | map(.value))`. (3/3)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the duplicate is NOT a duplicate, but a condition arising from a nested sub-grouping, which gives the appearance of a duplicate.  You should look to see if there is a switch to skip processing sub-groups when the upper-level meets the condition, thereby avoiding the perceived duplication.